# Python - Fractions module - Use limit_denominator issue or not?

Tags: python, module, fractions

I would like to share something that happened on my computer.
On my computer it is impossible to limit the denominator ....

```
a = fr.Fraction(0.3)
a.limit_denominator(100)
print(a)
```

And Python gave me that results:

```
5404319552844595/18014398509481984
```

[Screenshot of the results in using Jupyter Notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1T8G.png)

Is anyone knows if there is an issue with my code or this is an issue of Python ?

Python version: Python 3.8.2 (tags/v3.8.2:7b3ab59, Feb 25 2020, 23:03:10)
IDE: VS Code, Jupyter
OS Host: Windows 10 Pro - 64bits

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`limit_denominator` returns a new Fraction. Fractions are not supposed to be mutated, and nothing in the Fraction public API will mutate a Fraction.

Comment: How will you code it to have a fraction with a denominator not greater than 10 ?